# fa icon being overwritten by Disqus comment count

Tags: html, wordpress, font-awesome, disqus

I am trying to display a font awesome icon next to the comment count next to the word comment like this [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fbI-6Kef3pha8mLNtY0zXTznnOG1s5W6/view?usp=sharing). I want it so that clicking any area of the icon, count or the word comment will link to the post comment. However, I am running into an issue where Disqus comment count keeps overwriting my hyperlink.
Code 1: With the code below all I get is the comment count as in '0':

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>#disqus_thread"><i class="far fa-comments"></i>Comments</a>
```

Code 2: With the code below I get the effects I want but only the count is clickable, the comment icon and words comment are not

```
<span ><i class="far fa-comments"></i><a href="#disqus_thread"></a> comments</span>
```

With the final code I get three zeroes 0 0 0

```
<span >
    <a href="#disqus_thread"><i id="comment" class="far fa-comments"></i></a>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#disqus_thread"></a>
    <a href="#disqus_thread">comments</a>
</span>
```

This is a WordPress theme that I bought and the theme creator is not being very helpful. I would appreciate any help that I can get.

Thanks!

Comment: @Mech if that was the problem it would cause a syntax error and break the whole page, not just the functionality.

Comment: Not sure why the need for the `<span>` tags, but the reason for the second one not working correctly is because there is nothing between the `<a>` tags. This will work: `<span><a href="#disqus_thread"><i class="far fa-comments"></i> comments</a></span>`

Comment: @Mech for some reason whatever I put in the anchor tags is overwritten by Disqus comment count, so in the second scenario for example if I place a comment in the tags as you suggest, all I see is 0 or whatever the comment count is for that post

Comment: @codeblue001 Strange. I've added my CSS solution. Will that work for you?

Comment: Disqus is finding the `#disqus_thread` element and replacing it with the comment count. That's wy anything you put inside that element will be replaced. Thats also why you get 3 `0`s in the last code - you have the disqus_thread id 3 times. A CSS solution should work., you just need to make sure you add it to the correct element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CSS solution :)

```css
.comments::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f086";
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="#disqus_thread" class="comments"> comments</a>
```

Alternatively, you can add all of the content for the link via `CSS`:

```css
.comments::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f086  Comments";
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="#disqus_thread" class="comments"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks! the alternative method you suggested worked,  the first one was still causing the same error, my guess is it had something to do with the theme.